# website says failed to load resources and the code does not work, but when i refresh the site it works again, how do i fix this?

Tags: html, socket.io, http-status-code-404

I get the following error on my website:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) example.com/:1
```

I think its coming from my socket.io but i am not 100% certain, whenever i refresh the page the error goes away and it's like nothing is wrong. obviously i do not want to use that as a solution as a regular user on the site might not know that fixes it. heres my file structure in case it helps:

https://ibb.co/k1CjP2N

here is my html code too:

```
    <html lang="en"> 
        <head> 
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        
        <title>Double Trouble</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
        <script data-ad-client="ca-pub-8911022230234840" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <script type='application/javascript' src='./lib/fastclick.js'></script>
        <script src="./socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="./lib/phaser.js"></script>

    </head>
        <body>
            <p> example </p>
        </body>

        <script src="./src/game.js"></script>
    </html>
```

if you need to see more code, like the server.js or game.js i can share too, but i feel like the issue is stemming from here.

Comment: Should all the JS not go at the end of the document? Also, you're serving materialize.css but not materialize.js?

Comment: Thats correct, im using just the minimum build since i only need a few features. as for the javascript i was always taught that apis/libraries should got at the top. im away from the work computer but i will try and switch it and let you know. thank you!

Comment: The biggest issue is you don’t seem to be serving materialize.js